# Tab Bar controller - Tab bar could not set background image for portrait orientation for first time

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

In my ipad application,

**I am using ios 5.0.**

I have set tabbar's background image.

My application has a tab bar controller  and menuVC is one of the view controller.

My problem is

**When I am starting my app in portrait mode I could see the image of landscape mode.**

**1. In Appdelegate.**

```
if(menuVC.interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait  ||      menuVC.interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)

{ 

[tabBarController.tabBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"footerportrait.png"]];

}

else {

[tabBarController.tabBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"footerlandscape.png"]];

}
```

**2. In should autorotate to interface orientation.**

```
if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaeorientation))
{

[self.tabBarController.tabBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"footerportrait.png"]];

}
else 
{

[self.tabBarController.tabBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"footerlandscape.png"]];

}
```

**I do not know why this is happeninng.**

Thanks for helping.

I think that the problem is not of image but my navigation bar's width could be 1024.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, the interfaceOrientation property of an UIViewController is not valid when it has been created in the AppDelegate, only after `-viewDidAppear:animated` has been called. You could therefore set the background image in that method of your view controller.